# Spring application context : webapp folder variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Greetings,

Is there any Spring variable for Web application folder?
I want to assign a bean property as following.

Where **${WEBAPP-FOLDER}** is the absolute path of the web-app folder.

Any tips?

```
<bean id="compass" class="org.compass.spring.LocalCompassBean">
            .
                .
                <prop key="compass.engine.connection">file:///${WEBAPP-FOLDER}/WEB-INF/searchIndex</prop>       
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can obtain it through a `ServletContextListener`, by calling

```
event.getServletContext.getRealPath("/")
```

You can now set it in a `static` variable (which will logically be a constant), or get the spring application context and set it manually (via `WebApplicationUtils`) in the bean.

Comment: Thanks Bozho ,so if I set it in a static variable (say public static String WEBAPPFOLDER) in Listener , how can spring access it  ? just $WEBAPPFOLDER ?

Comment: well, not spring - you will access it directly `MyStaticHolder.WEBAPPFOLDER` - it won't be known to spring, just known to you.